Backup redis AOF to a bucket
I want to backup a snapshot of Redis once a day.
We already use AOF mechanism so I thought why not upload this file to a bucket as a Redis snapshot.
Is this a good practice? I think I can do it instead of running the BGSAVE command which will take more time and CPU.
